# Canceling Modal Dialog, not able to open the Dialog box again

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, custom-form, splistitem, modal-dialog

I have a modal Dialog Box confirmation and it works fine if I click Ok.  However, when I click cancel (lets say a user changes their mind) and decides a couple minutes later to activate the modal, nothing happens.  The background is grayed out but no dialog box.  I'm using the following to cancel:

```
    dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 400,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "update an item": function() {
            updateListItem();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
       form[0].reset();
       allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
    });
```

Anyone else ran into this issue?  I've seen others on here but it doesn't look related to what I'm facing.

Comment: Can you please provide a working demo in code pen?

Comment: Is there any error when you again try to open the dialog ?

Comment: No errors.   I have a link that starts the Modal Dialog.  The Dialog Box opens with the background html grayed out.  If I submit, it refreshes and submits to the list like it supposed to.  I can then click the link again to make changes.  However, If I click cancel, I am back to the page again.  Then when I click the link, no modal dialog box but the background is grayed.  So I have to refresh.  Does the cancel also have to have a reload element?

Comment: Ideally it should not. Can you try by refreshing the page once you click on cancel?

Comment: Yes, once I refresh, the page is reset and the link and Modal Dialog will work. It's just the Cancel button or the close button (the "x") will not refresh.

Comment: Re-Initiate the Dialog Object in your close function and check

Comment: I added the window.location.reload in the cancel button function and it refreshes now.  Thanks.